# MetaMask repeated errors with LocalHost

Tags: solidity, truffle, metamask

Every time I try to send ETH to my locally deployed contract I get errors like this:

[image]

-While the error message says "out of gas" I know that can't be true since all my accounts have like 100ETH in them.

-The address to which I'm trying to send the ETH is that of a crowdsale contract I successfully deployed to `localhost 8545` using `truffle migrate`

-I've tested this contract multiple times in `truffle console` by calling its functions - everything works fine, which is how I know its deployment was successful

-I'm not using `geth` or anything special - just `localhost 8545`

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently its a `MetaMask` quirk - you just need to reset it once in a while:

-go to `Settings` (tapping on the Icon in the top-right corner of the `MetaMask` window will bring out a menu, and if you scroll down that menu you'll eventually find `Settings`)

-Once in `Settings`, scroll down to, locate, and then tap on the `Reset Account` button

Voila.